# Foreach loop in LINQ without loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, active-directory

I have code below to bind active directory entries to an ASP.NET TreeView. It is working fine but I would like to achieve the same results using LINQ or Lambda expressions. My manager does not want to use foreach loop any of place in our application. So how can we bind these entries into treeview by using LINQ.

### Here is my page load foreach code:

```
foreach (DirectoryEntry firstChild in OUs)
{
    if (firstChild.SchemaClassName.Contains("organizationalUnit"))
    {
        TreeNode Node = new TreeNode(firstChild.Name.Substring(firstChild.Name.IndexOf('=') + 1));
        rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(Node);
        AddNodes(firstChild, Node);
    }
}

TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
```

### Recursive function to bind the tree node values:

```
private void AddNodes(DirectoryEntry entry, TreeNode node)
{
    foreach (DirectoryEntry child in entry.Children)
    {
        TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(child.Name.Substring(child.Name.IndexOf('=') + 1));
        node.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
        this.AddNodes(child, childNode);           
    }
}
```

Please could anyone suggest how to achieve the same result with LINQ or Lambda expression.

Comment: And how is converting that to LINQ gonna change execution time? Why would you even think LINQ would be a good use here?

Comment: @Tarec it's not strictly worse - it's a question of preference/readability. But I agree it wouldn't improve performance; written correctly it wouldn't degrade it much.

Comment: You can write whole fractal generators in LINQ (http://rasmuskjeldsen.blogspot.de/2007/11/mandelbrot-in-linq-to-objects.html), but should you?

Comment: @decPL I agree, but it's not like the LINQ is always increasing readability. In some cases it just doesn't make any sense to use it.

Comment: @Tarec then we agree completely :)

Comment: @BlueM: How this is possible for my code. I can't get you.

Comment: Performance wise LINQ can be worse than your loop http://www.schnieds.com/2009/03/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-loop-performance.html If you add the lesser readability you will get I don't see it too useful here.

Comment: @BlueM: If we use LINQ , it will execute 2 or 3 lines , it wont take more time. but using for loop it will execute continuously until the loop will get end, so it will take more time to execute.

Comment: @Suryakavitha What? I'm sorry, but I don't know how to comment that.. I really think should learn what a LINQ is and what's the point of using it.

Comment: @Tarec:Am new to LINQ, My manager does not want to use Foreach loop in our application. Thats why I asked this scenario with LINQ or Lambda expression. Is there any possiblities to use the same code in LINQ or Lambda expressions?

Comment: I flagged two of your previous as duplicates yesterday, and when I see this, I clearly have the feeling that you want us to write your code for you. People are here to help, not doing your job.

Comment: @Gnial0id: Not like that. I need your help only and valuable suggestions.I googled for this scenario but not able to get any proper idea. So I have totally blocked. By using stack overflow i can get different idea from you people thats why i have posted here. Its not mean that you to write code for me. Sorry!

Comment: Your manager is an idiot, tell him that arbitrarily ruling out foreach loops just because LINQ came up on his word-a-day toilet paper is ridiculous. LINQ has its uses but is hardly the best solution for every conceivable problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating this as a kind of code-golf, the following gives an idea as to how you can approach the problem from a functional mindset, where you try and 'flow' the results of one function through another (which is presumably what your manager is after).

Some changes are possible:

- Replacing the `if` with a filter predicate on the set
- By changing the recursive method `AddNodes()` to return the node, it can be used in a fluent style.

There also an obvious design mismatch given that `TreeViews` weren't designed with FP in mind, and instead encourage iterative mutation to the tree to build it up.
Sadly, `TreeNodeCollection` has no direct setter, nor an `AddRange`. So the horrid `ForEach` mutation seems necessary.

As a result, it is moot whether this constitutes any kind of improvement to your imperative original solution (Unless the rest of your code base is maintained by a bunch of F# or Haskell programmers). A `TreeView` which can be constructed in one projection would IMO be a pre-requisite for the switch to this approach.

```
// Recursive Funcs need to be forward-declared
Func<DirectoryEntry, TreeNode, TreeNode> addNodes = null;
addNodes = (entry, node) =>
    {
        entry.Children
           .Cast<DirectoryEntry>()
           .ToList() // Needed for ForEach
           .ForEach(
             child =>
               node.ChildNodes.Add(
                     addNodes(child,
                    new TreeNode(child.Name.Substring(child.Name.IndexOf('=') + 1)))));
        return node;
    };

OUs.Where(ou => ou.SchemaClassName.Contains("organizationalUnit"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(ou =>
            rootNode.ChildNodes.Add(addNodes(ou, 
                 new TreeNode(ou.Name.Substring(ou.Name.IndexOf('=') + 1)))));
treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
```

Comment: Sadly, this still uses `foreach` (ok, the `ForEach`-method). You could disguise it as `Select` (`.Select(child => {node.ChildNodes.Add...; return true;}).ToList()`;) so Suryakavitha's manager has nothing to complain about!!1!

Comment: @StuartLC: Its awesome. This is what exactly we need. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is: LINQ is used for collections selection, not for performing recursive loops. You can shorten your code

```
foreach(var dirEntry in OUs.Where(ou => ou.SchemaClassName.Contains("organizationalUnit")))
{
    AddNodes(dirEntry, rootNode);
}

TreeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
```

3 lines instead of 6, but that's IMO the only reasonable modification you can do.